# Why is my view getting offset when changing presentation styles?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, imessage

I have an iMessage extension and I'm having some issues with changing presentation styles. When I first open the app here is what I get:[image]
That's how it should be. Now when I change to expanded presentation style, this is what I get:[image]
That's also what I want. However, when I switch back to compact, this happens:[image]
Here is my code:

```
override func didTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    super.didTransition(to: presentationStyle)
    presentSearchStickersView()
}
private func presentSearchStickersView() {
    let controller = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchStickersViewController"))! as! SearchStickersViewController
    controller.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    controller.searchDelegate = self
    for child in childViewControllers {
        child.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        child.view.removeFromSuperview()
        child.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
    self.addChildViewController(controller)
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my top constraint:[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view you should not reinstantiate the bar every time you switch to compact or extend mode. You should instantiate it once, then set constraints to the top of the view. I've tried that way and it's working fine ;)

So to sum up, if you are using the storyboard

1. In your storyboard add your subview to the controller
2. Set a Top constraint, width equal to superview and centerX to superview
3. In the code set your search bar (delegate etc) in viewdidload

If you are not using storyboard.

1. load your xib and add it to your subview (maybe in the didBecomeActive or something like that)
2. Don't forget to set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false
3. Add the same constraints as above

Comment: I did that but in expanded the top part of my view was getting hidden behind the navigation bar. That's why I represented the view controller

Comment: Have you used "Top Layout Guide" constraint?

Comment: Yes, I used 'Top Layout Guide." I'm adding a screenshot

Comment: Ok, I removed the code that re-presents the view controller and I'm getting the exact same issue with storyboard constraints alone. I really wish view debugging was available in iMessage extensions.

Comment: Which beta are you using?

Comment: I'll try tonight your configuration ;)

Comment: Beta 4 is out, maybe try to update your Xcode and iOS ;)

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Meanwhile I figured out that if I embed the stack view in the initial view controller I have no issues. However, I have the issue when presenting another view controller with the stack view.

Comment: Ohhh right, I didn't see your were using a stack view! Do you really need it here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120184/discussion-between-romone-and-a-tyshka).

Answer (score 0):

As RomOne said you should be putting it there once. Style switches should be handled by constraints